# Re-process emails from `/var/mail/root`

Tags: linux, email, imap, freebsd, sendmail

The mail forwarding was broken on one of my servers. Some emails accumulated in the local `/var/mail/root` mailbox instead of being forwarded. I fixed the forwarding now. Is there a way of reprocessing those emails so that they are re-sent?

I am asking that because when the email is forwarded to another server, the other server applies some filtering and processing to put the emails to appropriate folders accessible through IMAP.

Alternatively, would it be possible to convert the `/var/mail/root` mailbox file to a set of emails that could be copied directly to an IMAP folder (e.g. I could copy the file across to the other server manually).

Comment: Use formail from the procmail package. See https://serverfault.com/questions/90023/how-can-i-send-var-mail-root-again

Comment: That's great! Thanks! Why didn't you post it as an answer? :)

Comment: I tried but stackoverflow automagically converted it to a comment, because it thinks it is a "trivial answer"

Answer (score 1):

Well, the file *already* is a set of emails (a "mbox" format file). To copy its contents to IMAP, you can run `mutt -f /var/mail/root` and use the <kbd>Shift+C</kbd> (copy) or <kbd>s</kbd> (move) commands, and enter `imap://user@mail.example.com` as the destination.

To convert the mbox file to Maildir format (assuming your IMAP server uses Maildir), you would do exactly the same but specify a local directory path as the destination, e.g. `/tmp/rootmail/`. (Note that the final `/` is important – without it, you'd just get another mbox file.)

Comment: Yeah, I meant a set of separate files. Emails are always separate, no matter if they are stored in mbox or maildir, as you rightly pointed out. I don't have `mutt` installed by default and so will try to first investigate if there are other options with more standard tools before trying your proposal.